# php cake get value of radio button in html then pass to controller

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I need help in getting the value of the radio button and using it as a variable in php cake controller.

```
              <li class="search-pref-list-items__item"><label><input type="radio" name="pref" value="1">a</label></li>
          <li class="search-pref-list-items__item"><label><input type="radio" name="pref" value="2">b</label></li>
          <li class="search-pref-list-items__item"><label><input type="radio" name="pref" value="3">c</label></li>
```

I already tried  $this->request->data  but it only works on textbox,
$_GET[] and $_POST[] are also now working

how will I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Rey Norbert Besmonte,

You need to create radio buttons by following cakephp method.
Please refere my code as below to create radio button by following cakephp framework standard.

```
$options = array('a'=>'1','b'=>'2','c'=>'3');
$attributes = array('div' => 'input', 'type' => 'radio', 'options' => $options,'class' => 'search-pref-list-items__item' ,'default' => '1');
echo $this->Form->radio('Filed Name',$attributes);
```

So you need to remove  from your code and place above code.

Hope this will help you.